# This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: linux, ssh, tar

I'm trying to fast copy some big directories from my remote Debian 9 server to my local Debian 9 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for linux; Windows 10 Pro) with `ssh "tar" | tar` pipe.

```
ssh user@example.com "cd /path/to/resource && tar czf - resource1 resource2" | tar xzvf -
```

When I run this command I get the error messages

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
>      tar: Child died with signal 13
>      tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

If I do the same without the `z`parameter

```
ssh user@example.com "cd /path/to/resource && tar cf - resource1 resource2" | tar xvf -
```

I get these errors:

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive
>   tar: Skipping to next header

with no prompt.

I've run this command several times before on different hardware and in this particular case I just have re-run this command from my bash_history from some days ago. It has been run then, but it doesn't run now.

If I use `scp` instead with compression enabled (which will be much slower)

```
scp -rC user@example.com:/path/to/resource/resource1 .
```

I get this error:

> protocol error: mtime.sec not present

**What can I do to make this work?**

tar version
Local: tar (GNU tar) 1.29
Remote: tar (GNU tar) 1.29

bash version
Local: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Remote: GNU bash, Version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Linux version (cat /proc/version)
Local : Linux version 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #523-Microsoft Mon Dec 31 17:49:00 PST 2018
Remote: Linux version 4.9.0-5-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04)

Comment: Do you get any additional output when you connect via ssh to that host? a welcome message of some kind?

Comment: Your question led me in the right direction. I have a `~/.profile` script which has an output that destroys the tar pipe

Answer (score 1):

This was an error on the remote server. For some program I run there (tig) I need a 256 color xterm and I set it by this script. I only installed it recently.

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
    echo TERM set to 256 colors
elif [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
    echo TERM set to 256 colors
else
    export TERM='xterm-color'
    echo TERM set to color
fi
```

I needed to get rid of the echos and it runs again

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
elif [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
    export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

Thanks to [Gerald Schneider](https://serverfault.com/users/38644/gerald-schneider) for the hint

Please pay attention to [chutz](https://serverfault.com/users/114782/chutz)'s comment below

Comment: If you are putting stuff like this in a `.bashrc` or `.profile`, which are sourced even for non-interactive shells, then you better make sure you only do this when the shell is interactive. An easy way to sort this is by putting this at the start `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return`